# How to merge two tables in case of many-to-one columns by one SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to merge tables by one query in PostgerSQL by Python.
Suppose we have two tables 'order_tbl' and 'personnel_tbl' as below.

[image]

What I want to get is following w/ original 2names and age & are wgt the 2names for all rows.

[image]

If what I want is only name1 info, SQL will be following.

```
SELECT 
order_tbl.sales, order_tbl.name1, personnel_tbl.age, personnel_tbl.area
FROM order_tbl
INNER JOIN personnel_tbl
ON order_tbl.name1 = personnel_tbl.name;
```

I can successfully get all rows with only name1 info. But I cannot come up with a query of SQL for name1 and name2.
Could someone give me a clue?
Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
SELECT order_tbl.sales As uriage, p1.name As name1, p2.name As name1, p1.age, 
       p1.area, p2.age, p2.area
FROM order_tbl INNER JOIN personnel_tbl As p1 ON order_tbl.name1 = p1.name
               INNER JOIN personnel_tbl As p2 ON order_tbl.name2 = p2.name
```

Comment: Thank you for your clue. It worked as well. One of my colleagues gave me almost same answer as yours, only INNER JOIN is slightly different from yours like,

INNER JOIN perssonel_tbl t1 ON name1=t1.name
INNER JOIN personnel_tbl t2 ON name1=t2.name

This worked as well.

Comment: You are welcome. It was pleasure to help.